# Are there any sites which creates and stores database for iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, web-services, json, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I know about http://www.kumulos.com/ which allows us to easily create database for iphone and store it there. They also let you create APIs to connect to this database.

Only problem is that I am not sure whether we can access this database for viewing it on a asp.net website.

I would like to know if there are any other sites which does similar thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access Kumulos from an asp.NET using the JSON protocol.

There is example PHP code and its very simple to do, would be easy to accomplish the same thing in ASP.

http://www.kumulos.com/2011/01/25/accessing-kumulos-apis-and-database-from-php/